# Designing a windows application to maintain states across MDI child forms

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, ooad

It's a pretty long post and I shall try my best to explain the working of the application that I have developed and want your assistance in extending it for the future.

I need to design a windows based application in C# which basically monitors events from an external communication source and plots the data on a graph. The application subscribes to events from communication objects and updates the UI as and when there are data events. A graph component inside these monitoring classes will use the data inside the communication data buffers to plot the data as a line graph.

[image]

To achieve this, I have created a Factory class which will instantiate a particular monitoring class (CWindowFirst or CWindowSecond etc) based on Model information I provide (device model type).

These classes implement standard contract (IFactoryInterface) for initialization , data acquisition and cleanup operations. So at any given point of time I can instantiate a particular class and start the monitoring operation to receive the data and populate the graph in the process. So far so good, I can display the data in the form of a graph for a particular device.Also at the moment I'm destroying(disposing) the object of CWindowFirst whenever the main application chooses another window (i.e. CWindowSecond or CWindowThird).

As the saying goes in "SW development the only constant is the Change", A new requirement has come up where I need to give the user an option to Pause/Stop feature for the graph. 
I should be able to Pause the graph (i.e. pause the data communication )  and go to main window play around and also should be able to open another window (CWindowSecond) play there around a bit with the graph again (should be able to pause the communication here as well).  Come back to the first window CWindowFirst and resume the previously saved data communication.

Now comes the million $ question, how do I achieve or rather modify the existing design to implement the feature as described above.

I can think of the following implementation but I'm not sure if its really a pragmatic one.

On issue of Pause command I shall

1. Stop the communication (unsubscribe communication event) on Pause.
2. Save the state of the event data buffers and graph in a collection.
3. Serialize the complete object to a file before exit.
4. On return to the same form, I shall deserialize the object
5. Get the event data buffer from the deserialized object
6. Populate in the graph and enable the event handlers so that I continue to receive events from the communication layer.

Experts out there I need your assistance out here. Please guide / suggest improvements / share your idea

Comment: What type of communications?  Are you monitoring multicast or tcp?  Are you the master (client) or slave (server).  Answers are needed to come up with correct architecture. Do you have to send command to server to stop sending?

Comment: The communication is via TCP. Although my application frankly doesn't care if its via TCP/USB Serial. It basically just a slave (receiver). If I subscribe communication events, I receive the data if I unsubscribe I wont  get data

Comment: When unpause, is it: 1) continuing from where it left, 2) reset the screen, 3) render all the pending data instantly then continue from there?

Comment: 1. Yes, on unpause it shall restart from where it had left----2.No, it shall not reset the screen----3.Yes it has to continue (even if it could mean the data loss in between the time period when Paused and Unpause)

Comment: Separate the data from the view.  Do not use MDI if you only allow a single child window to be visible, a UserControl is just simpler.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks for your advice. I shall separate the data from the view.Unfortunately I cannot change the MDI window handling part as the framework part is part of the application framework.

Comment: Separate receiving with displaying. Received data - store it in the buffer - copy buffer - show UI from copy of the buffer. Then you can pause and do whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

As HansPassant commented, separate the data (or context, or manager, whatever) from view. [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with context constructor injection is the best bet here IMHO.

Example by using the non-cleanest way of singleton:

```
public class MonitoringContext {
    public static MonitoringContext CurrentContext = new MonitoringContext();

    // handle generating data
    // handle populating data needed for graph
    // handle other action from other forms as well
}

public class FormGraph : Form{
    // default constructor if you do not have access to MDI
    public FormGraph(){
        this.context = MonitoringContext.CurrentContext;
    }
    public FormGraph(MonitoringContext context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    MonitoringContext context;

    // do whatever you want with context
}

public class FormOther : Form{
    // default constructor if you do not have access to MDI
    public FormOther(){
        this.context = MonitoringContext.CurrentContext;
    }
    public FormOther(MonitoringContext context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    MonitoringContext context;

    // do whatever you want with context
    // any changes reflected at the FormGraph
    // because of same reference and mutability
}
```

Of course this is suggested approach from outsider who do not know the requirement and current architecture deep down and detailed. Any adjustment should be made to fulfill the requirement.